# Use hfill in array

Tags: spacing, arrays

I want to have two equations, in two lines, the first the most at left, the second, the most at right:

```
equation 1  
      equation 2
```

So, the newbie in me try to do

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{
  \[
    \begin{array}{l}
      equation 1\hfill\\
      \hfill equation 2
    \end{array}
  \]
}

\end{document}
```

which, of course, does not work.

I can replace the `\hfill` by a specific `\hspace{size}`, but it is not what I want: I want the space to be added to be calculated automatically.

One (horrible) way to make it work is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\twoEq}[2]{
  \begin{array}{p{\linewidth}}
    \(\displaystyle{#1}\hfill\)\\
    \(\displaystyle\hfill{#2}\)
  \end{array}
}
\begin{document}

\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{
  \[
    \twoEq{equation 1}{equation 2}
  \]
}

\end{document}
```

Can somebody propose a more elegant solution?

Comment: you might try `multline` from `amsmath`: `\begin{multline*} equation 1 \\ equation 2 \end{multline*}`.  this uses the full page width, so you might want to put it into a `minipage`.

Comment: `array` isn't really suitable for display equations, it sets each cell in inline mode and is designed for arrays/matrices. `multline` is designed for the layout you describe as indicated by barabara.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for! I added your comment as an answer, but please, fell free to add it by yourself and I remove mine.

Comment: Your horrible workaround was actually the best (or only?) working option in my situation, so I would like to upvote your question as an answer. ;-) Just note that you should prevent the array from adding left and right margins, hence `\begin{array}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}` with `@{}` on the left and right sides of the array format specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `multlined` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{multlined}[.3\displaywidth]
  overlong equation 1\\
  overlong equation 2
\end{multlined}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks! I still prefer Barbara's solution, just because I already use amsmath for other things, but it is nice to see that there are several elegant solutions.

Comment: `mathtools` is an extention to `amsmath`. It even loads `amsmath` if you haven't already.

Comment: I just realize that this solution is better, because it works even in a `\[...\]` environment, while `multline` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{
  \[
    \begin{array}{lr}
      equation 1 & \\
      & equation 2
    \end{array}
  \]
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case you will have the first equation in the first column and the second in the second, which is not what I want. I want them to overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Barbara Beeton gave the following nice answer in a comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{
  \begin{multline*}
    equation 1\\
    equation 2
  \end{multline*}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\parbox` should go *inside* `\[...\]` and a `minipage` seems better: `\[\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}\begin{multline*}...\end{multline*}\end{minipage}\]`

Comment: Thanks, I removed the `\[...\]` directly, because they are not needed.

Comment: Sorry, but they *are* necessary, unless you want your equation next to the left margin with the normal indent.

Comment: Mmmm... but in that case you are using `\[...\]` for `\begin{center}...\end{center}`. The thing is that `multline` only work in text mode, not in math mode (that is way I accepted your answer as the best answer for this question, because `multlined` can be used even in mathmode).